# AngularJS - best place to handle an error in MVC

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Where is it best to handle both error handling, and error display? E.g.

I have a controller:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.form = {
            username: ''
        };

        $scope.login = function () {
            doSomething($scope.form.username);
        };
    });
```

And a view bound to the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input ng-model="username.form" />
    <button ng-click="login()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

If `$scope.form.username` is blank, this is an error; where is it best to handle this? In the controller, e.g.:

```
if ($scope.form.username == '') {
    // do something here
}
```

Or just pass the value to `doSomething(...)` and let that function handle a blank value?

Secondly, what's the best method to update the element (say, to highlight the input red or to show a small message underneath) to indicate that an error has occured?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the article about the angular form validation (http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html). It provides everything you need to set a good form validation.

After this, you can implement a check on Submit to prevent submitting the form if there are validation errors :

```
    $scope.signupForm = function() {
        if ($scope.signup_form.$valid) {
          // Submit as normal
        } else {
          //no submit, notify the user 
        }
    ...}
```

And for the error messages, as they are rendered in the view, you can manage them directly in your directive like :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" ng-model="signup.name"       ng-minlength=3  ng-maxlength=20 required />
       <div class="error-container" ng-show="signup_form.name.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid && signup_form.submitted">
        <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.name.$error.required">
            Your name is required.
        </small>
```